# Capitalize first letter. MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, capitalize

Does any one know the equivalent to this TSQL in MySQL parlance?

I am trying to capitalize the first letter of each entry.

```
UPDATE tb_Company SET CompanyIndustry = UPPER(LEFT(CompanyIndustry, 1))
+ SUBSTRING(CompanyIndustry, 2, LEN(CompanyIndustry))
```

Answer (score 336, accepted):

It's almost the same, you just have to change to use the CONCAT() function instead of the + operator :

```
UPDATE tb_Company
SET CompanyIndustry = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(CompanyIndustry, 1)), 
                             SUBSTRING(CompanyIndustry, 2));
```

This would turn `hello` to `Hello`, `wOrLd` to `WOrLd`, `BLABLA` to `BLABLA`, etc. If you want to upper-case the first letter and lower-case the other, you just have to use LCASE function :

```
UPDATE tb_Company
SET CompanyIndustry = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(CompanyIndustry, 1)), 
                             LCASE(SUBSTRING(CompanyIndustry, 2)));
```

Note that UPPER and UCASE do the same thing.

Comment: thanks - that did what I needed. I forgot to mention that I needed to set to lower case first. thanks

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work? UPDATE tb_Company
SET CompanyIndustry = CONCAT(UCASE(SUBSTRING(CompanyIndustry, 1,1)), 
                             LCASE(SUBSTRING(CompanyIndustry, 2)));

Answer (score 70):

Vincents excellent answer for Uppercase **First** Letter works great for the first letter **only** capitalization of an entire column string..

**BUT what if you want to Uppercase the First Letter of EVERY word** in the strings of a table column?

eg: "Abbeville High School"

I hadn't found an answer to this in Stackoverflow. I had to cobble together a few answers I found in Google to provide a solid solution to the above example. Its not a native function but a user created function which MySQL version 5+ allows.

If you have Super/Admin user status on MySQL or have a local mysql installation on your own computer you can create a FUNCTION (like a stored procedure) which sits in your database and can be used in all future SQL query on any part of the db.

The function I created allows me to use this new function I called "UC_Words" just like the built in native functions of MySQL so that I can update a complete column like this:

```
UPDATE Table_name
SET column_name = UC_Words(column_name)
```

To insert the function code, I changed the MySQL standard delimiter(;) whilst creating the function, and then reset it back to normal after the function creation script. I also personally wanted the output to be in UTF8 CHARSET too.

Function creation =

```
DELIMITER ||  

CREATE FUNCTION `UC_Words`( str VARCHAR(255) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8 DETERMINISTIC  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);  
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(255);  
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;  
  DECLARE bool INT DEFAULT 1;  
  DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_!@;:?/';  
  SET s = LCASE( str );  
  WHILE i < LENGTH( str ) DO  
     BEGIN  
       SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );  
       IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN  
        SET bool = 1;  
      ELSEIF bool=1 THEN  
        BEGIN  
          IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN  
             BEGIN  
               SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));  
               SET bool = 0;  
             END;  
           ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN  
            SET bool = 0;  
          END IF;  
        END;  
      END IF;  
      SET i = i+1;  
    END;  
  END WHILE;  
  RETURN s;  
END ||  

DELIMITER ;
```

This works a treat outputting Uppercase first letters on multiple words within a string.

Assuming your MySQL login username has sufficient privileges - if not, and you cant set up a temporary DB on your personal machine to convert your tables, then ask your shared hosting provider if they will set this function for you.

Comment: `CHARSET utf8_general_ci` should be changed to `CHARSET utf8` (at least on 5.7)

Comment: @ManuelDallaLana actually you could get error `Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'` so I think just fix the charset or remove it and make it on default.

Comment: @Alejandro This answer capitalizes the first letter of each word in the string. The question and the accepted answer only capitalize the first letter in the string. They are both super helpful answers but for different use cases.

Comment: There is an error, you must declare 's' with charset "DECLARE s VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8;" or you will loose some characters. Thanks for this solution anyway :-)

Comment: And also 'c':  "DECLARE c CHAR(1) CHARSET utf8;"

Comment: In MySQL 8, `utf` should be changed to `utfmb4` or else you'll get a warning.

Answer (score 20):

You can use a combination of `UCASE()`, `MID()` and `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(MID(name,1,1)),MID(name,2)) AS name FROM names;
```

Comment: this doesn't lower all other letters. Try `SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(MID('TEST',1,1)),MID('TEST',2));`

Answer (score 9):

```
mysql> SELECT schedule_type AS Schedule FROM ad_campaign limit 1;
+----------+
| Schedule |
+----------+
| ENDDATE  |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(MID(schedule_type,1,1)),LCASE(MID(schedule_type,2))) AS Schedule FROM ad_campaign limit 1;
+----------+
| Schedule |
+----------+
| Enddate  |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_mid

Answer (score 7):

This is working nicely.

```
UPDATE state SET name = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(name, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(name, 2)));
```

Answer (score 5):

http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=201

If there are more than 1 word in the column, then this will not work as shown below.
The UDF mentioned above may help in such case.

```
mysql> select * from names;
+--------------+
| name         |
+--------------+
| john abraham | 
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(MID(name,1,1)),MID(name,2)) AS name FROM names;
+--------------+
| name         |
+--------------+
| John abraham | 
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or maybe this one will help...

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_str#str_ucwords

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tb_Company SET CompanyIndustry = UCASE(LEFT(CompanyIndustry, 1)) + 
SUBSTRING(CompanyIndustry, 2, LEN(CompanyIndustry))
```

Comment: i was just trying to highlight the UCASE function in MySQL :P :)

Answer (score 2):

CREATE A FUNCTION:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `UC_FIRST`(`oldWord` VARCHAR(255)) 

RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8

RETURN CONCAT( UCASE( LEFT(oldWord, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(oldWord, 2)))
```

USE THE FUNCTION

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET col_name = UC_FIRST(col_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

> If anyone try to capitalize the every word separate by space...

```
CREATE FUNCTION response(name VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS VARCHAR(200) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   set @m='';
   set @c=0;
   set @l=1;
   while @c <= char_length(name)-char_length(replace(name,' ','')) do
      set @c = @c+1;
      set @p = SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',@c);
      set @k = substring(name,@l,char_length(@p)-@l+1);
      set @l = char_length(@k)+2;
      set @m = concat(@m,ucase(left(@k,1)),lcase(substring(@k,2)),' ');
   end while;
   return trim(@m); 
END;
CREATE PROCEDURE updateNames()
BEGIN
  SELECT response(name) AS name FROM names;
END;
```

> Result

```
+--------------+
| name         |
+--------------+
| Abdul Karim  | 
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work nicely:

```
UPDATE tb_Company SET CompanyIndustry = 
CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(CompanyIndustry, 1)), SUBSTRING(CompanyIndustry, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users
SET first_name = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(first_name, 1)), 
                             LCASE(SUBSTRING(first_name, 2)))
,last_name = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(last_name, 1)), 
                             LCASE(SUBSTRING(last_name, 2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select  CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT('CHRIS', 1)),SUBSTRING(lower('CHRIS'),2));
```

Above statement can be used for first letter CAPS and rest as lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in PostgreSQL (as far as googling may lead to this page)

```
INITCAP(firstname || ' ' || lastname) AS fullname
```

Comment: The title clearly  say MYSQL

Comment: @Youness as far as google leads to this thread so I clearly stated the limitations the answer can be applied. But you are right title is about MySQL answer is about PostreSQL

Answer (score -3):

Uso algo simples assim ;)

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `uc_frist` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `uc_frist` (str VARCHAR(200)) RETURNS varchar(200)
BEGIN
    set str:= lcase(str);
    set str:= CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(str, 1)),SUBSTRING(str, 2));
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' a', ' A');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' b', ' B');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' c', ' C');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' d', ' D');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' e', ' E');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' f', ' F');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' g', ' G');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' h', ' H');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' i', ' I');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' j', ' J');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' k', ' K');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' l', ' L');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' m', ' M');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' n', ' N');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' o', ' O');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' p', ' P');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' q', ' Q');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' r', ' R');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' s', ' S');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' t', ' T');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' u', ' U');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' v', ' V');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' w', ' W');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' x', ' X');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' y', ' Y');
    set str:= REPLACE(str, ' z', ' Z');
    return  str;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Dude... this is the opposite of simple..