# How to lowercase the whole string keeping the first in uppercase in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table column -

[image]

My expected Output to change in column -

```
Smith, Allen, Doyle, Dennis, Baker, Waker
```

This is what i tried, but not working :( -

```
UPDATE TABLE `employee`
SET last_name = UCASE(LEFT(lower(last_name), 1))

UPDATE TABLE `employee`
SET last_name = ucase(lower(last_name),1)
```

Followed this link too - [Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql)

ERROR --

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE `employee` SET last_name = UCASE(LEFT(lower(last_name), 1))' at line 1
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong and how to fix.

Comment: @sfah can you please specify more that which part of the question/answer is relevant in my context as I m totally confused with the link you provided for this ?? or better add an answer :)

Comment: @swapnesh what is the name of your table? see my answer below.

Comment: @JW. Thx its working plz find my additional comment under the answer

Comment: @JW. although your previously added answer was also working..just for the curiosity i am asking why you edit that even though thats working too

Comment: that new query is shorter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TABLE` is a reserved keyword. It should be escaped with backtick.

I think `TABLE` should not be in your query, (*i think it is a typo*)

```
UPDATE employee
SET last_Name = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(last_Name, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(last_Name, 2)))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7dc0/1)

Comment: Thanks for the working solution and the fiddle, but will you please expand a lit bit about the backtick comments as I really feel uncomfortable with these when to use or not (although in this case its working with backtick inclusion and exclusion as well)

Comment: @swapnesh here are the list if [MySQL rserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). if you use any of the following, a backtick is required to escape.

Comment: very sincere thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 2):

try this it may work

```
update `employee` 
set name=concat(left(upper(last_name),1),right(lower(last_name),length(last_name)-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone here is looking also how to upper case First Name and Last Name in say a Name column that contains both, here is a snippet that maybe useful:

```
 SELECT
    CONCAT( 
     UCASE(LEFT(substring_index(name, ' ',1),1)), 
     LCASE(SUBSTRING(substring_index(name, ' ',1),2)),
    ' ',
     UCASE(LEFT(substring_index(name, ' ',-1),1)), 
     LCASE(SUBSTRING(substring_index(name, ' ',-1),2))
    ) as name
FROM table
```