# Change lower case to upper (title) case using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, title-case

i want to change case using sql query

e.g if text is : `My nAme is iShAn halaRNkar` (text is jumbled i.e it may contain Lower case or Upper case anywhere in the senetence)

than i want the output to be : `My Name Is Ishan Halarnkar`

i have not worked on sql queries much. Kindly help.

Comment: This will be helpful for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql

Comment: Which RDBMS? SQL Server, MySQL or ?? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such function in any database which do this for you. You've to write a function which actually performs the check on each word in a sentence. Please check the solutions below:

**MySql:**

```
DELIMITER //

    CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))

    RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

    DETERMINISTIC

    BEGIN
        DECLARE len INT;
        DECLARE i INT;

        SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
        SET input = LOWER(input);
        SET i = 0;

        WHILE (i < len) DO
            IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
                IF (i < len) THEN
                    SET input = CONCAT(
                        LEFT(input,i),
                        UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                        RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                    );
                END IF;
            END IF;
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;

        RETURN input;
    END//

DELIMITER ;
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT CAP_FIRST('this is exACtly tHe same!')
```

**Output:**

```
This Is Exactly The Same!
```

**Copyrights:**

http://joezack.com/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/

Hope this helps!

Comment: this looks exactly like what i need - but where and how do I add this function to my mysql?

Comment: @daniel Crabbe - Please accept my apologies for late reply. However, you simply need to execute the above script on `mysql terminal` with required privileges `INSERT` to add the user-defined function. And then simply execute the sql command as show in the given example.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another Microsoft SQL function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION PROPERCASE(@TEXT AS VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RESET BIT;
   DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX);
   DECLARE @I INT;
   DECLARE @C CHAR(1);

   SELECT @RESET = 1, @I=1, @STR = '';

   WHILE (@I <= LEN(@TEXT))
    SELECT @C= SUBSTRING(@TEXT,@I,1),
               @STR = @STR + CASE WHEN @RESET=1 THEN UPPER(@C) ELSE LOWER(@C) END,
               @RESET = CASE WHEN @C LIKE '[A-ZA-Z]' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
               @I = @I +1
   RETURN @STR
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This SQL should work.

`SELECT UPPER(LEFT(<ColumnName>, 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(<ColumnName>,LEN(<ColumnName>)-1)) FROM {YourTableName}`

Comment: It capitalises only the 1st letter of a sentence instead of 1st letter of each word

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create function

```
CREATE FUNCTION ProperCase(@OriginalText VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)  
BEGIN 
DECLARE @CleanedText VARCHAR(8000) 
;with
  a1 as (select 1 as N union all select 1 union all
         select 1      union all select 1 union all
         select 1      union all select 1 union all
         select 1      union all select 1 union all
         select 1      union all select 1),
  a2 as (select 1 as N from a1 as a cross join a1 as b),
  a3 as (select 1 as N from a2 as a cross join a2 as b),
  a4 as (select 1 as N from a3 as a cross join a2 as b),
  Tally as (select top (len(@OriginalText)) row_number() over (order by N) as N from a4)

SELECT @CleanedText = ISNULL(@CleanedText,'') +  
     --first char is always capitalized?
CASE WHEN Tally.N = 1 THEN UPPER(SUBSTRING(@OriginalText,Tally.N,1))
     WHEN SUBSTRING(@OriginalText,Tally.N -1,1) = ' '  THEN UPPER(SUBSTRING(@OriginalText,Tally.N,1))
     ELSE LOWER(SUBSTRING(@OriginalText,Tally.N,1))
END

FROM Tally           WHERE Tally.N
```

Now you just use this function

```
select dbo.ProperCase('My nAme is iShAn halaRNkar')
```