# Query giving wrong answer

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql I want first letter of firstname capital and remaining characters in lower case the query i am using is

```
select  UPPER(LEFT(FirstName,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(FirstName,2,LENGTH(FirstName))) FirstName from colliers;
```

this gives answer 0, but it works perfectly in SQL server ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). "Plus sign" concatenation doesn't work in MySQL. You will probably end up with something like this :

```
select CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(FirstName,1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(FirstName,2,LENGTH(FirstName)))) FirstName from colliers;
```

By the way you don't need `LENGTH(FirstName)` in the [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function call.  When the third parameter is omitted `SUBSTRING()` assume you want the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `CONCAT()`, instead of +

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(FirstName,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(FirstName,2,LENGTH(FirstName)))) FirstName from colliers
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way to solve the problem!

I would use concat(), ucase()/upper(), lcase()/lower(), mid()/substring()

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        upper(mid(Firstname, 1, 1))
        ,lower(mid(Firstname, 2))
        )
FROM colliers;
```