# Error in ucfirst in Mysql

Tags: mysql

In Select query I'm using ucfirst for getting character in caps.

My Select Query:

```
SELECT det.Id AS id,
       ucfirst(det.title) AS title,
       DATE_FORMAT((det.dateInt), '%M %d, %Y') AS dateint
FROM img_details det
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

When I'm using this query in Mysql it is showing error like:

```
FUNCTION admin.ucfirst does not exist.
```

Please give any suggestions.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to all character in capital letter or first character of word capitalize?

Comment: Visit this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql

Comment: I want only first letter in caps @Sadikhasan

Answer (score 0):

Try with `UCASE` function in  mysql. There is no function available in mysql named with `ucfirst`

```
SELECT det.Id AS id,
       UCASE(det.title) AS title,
       DATE_FORMAT((det.dateInt), '%M %d, %Y') AS dateint
FROM img_details det
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Comment: It is working but everything coming in caps.I need only first letter to be in Caps.Thanks for your answer @Sadikhasan