# Python - Create SQL Table with Capital Letter

Tags: python, mysql, create-table

I'm learning the basics of MySQL using Python. When creating tables, they will always be named without any formatting, and ignore formatting I use in the script. How can I adjust my code to add a capital when creating a table? Sorry if this is quite basic, my current knowledge means its hard for me to use the answers of relevant questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql).

My query:

```
SQL_Create_Table = """ CREATE TABLE Employee """
```

Comment: Trying to make table names case-sensitive is usually not a good idea; or generally worth-while.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134006/are-table-names-in-mysql-case-sensitive)

Comment: Understood, I wont worry about formatting such as this. I would still be interested in seeing an answer however.

Comment: Are you using Windows? MySQL saves table names as lower case by default on Windows so you could (but shouldn't) edit [lower_case_table_names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names).

Comment: Yes Windows 10 64-bit, do you know how this can be changed?

Comment: @LaurieBamber the entry I linked covers the topic fairly thoroughly... as far as I know it cannot be changed on a Windows system at all.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Also, that link you just added in has no relevance; it is about changing the case of the contents of the field, not the name of the field.

Answer (score 1):

From MySQL's docs:

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory. Consequently, the case sensitivity
>   of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case
>   sensitivity of database and table names.

Therefore, on Windows, tables names aren't case sensitive by default, while on most Unix / Linux distributions, they will be case sensitive.

If you want to modify the default behavior, you can modify this configuration in `my.cnf / my.ini`: `lower_case_table_names`

[More information about this configuration key here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names).

Comment: The docs explicitly say "You should not set lower_case_table_names to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system where the data directory resides on a case-insensitive file system (such as on Windows or macOS)"

Comment: Yep, thanks for the help but will just move forward without caring about the formatting.