# Capitalize first letter only in USA customer name

Tags: mysql, sql

Need a MySQL query to update the customer first letter of the name is Capitalized and the remaining letters are lower case.

In cases where the Last name begins with the following: (Fitz, Mac, Mc, and O’) we should capitalize the following letter:

Example: McDonald, MacIntyre, O'Neal, etc.

```
SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(SUBSTRING(field, 1, 1)),LCASE(SUBSTRING(field, 2))) 
FROM table_name WHERE field REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z]+$';
```

I expect the output of to "mcdonald, macintyre, o'neal" be "McDonald, MacIntyre, O'Neal"

Comment: What if the surname is Mackie?

Comment: I am satisfied with you. I also asked the client but he wants to this.

Comment: Defining such a regular expression for the last name will be problematic, as there is no explicit grammar defined that will cover all possibilities without including false positives.

Comment: I am very frustrated. I already took a very long time for this query. so please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql

Comment: If it's what the client wants, this may require a bit of manual work. I'd start with capitalizing the first letters of the first and last names, then reviewing a set of special cases where the last name includes two capital letters and adjusting accordingly.

Comment: The SQL to do this would be pretty horrendous and quite unreadable - is there any reason you couldn't do this after receiving the query results?

Is there any reason you don't perform an ETL to 'clean up' the troublesome data?

Comment: Yes, Actually, We tried to server-side script and script was taking a very long time.
We have big data of customer so we decided that will work on SQL.

Comment: So please if any have solution then please suggest me.

Comment: I wonder how Emmanuel MacRon would feel about this.  And I haven't seen names spelled like FitzGerald or FitzSimmons.  I don't think the requirement is well thought out.

Comment: Hey dhiru if you think my answer is valid can you mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do last name transformation in MySQL you would need to do something like this.

**NOTE:** this is merely handling the 'macdonald => MacDonald' scenario.

```
SELECT 
   CASE
      WHEN INSTR(LCASE(Field), "mac") == 1 THEN 
         CONCAT(
           "Mac", 
           UCASE(SUBSTRING(Field,4,1)),
           LCASE(SUBSTRING(Field,5))
         )
      ELSE CONCAT(UCASE(SUBSTRING(Field,1,1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(Field,2)))
   END AS surname
FROM table_name;
```

Just add more 'when' statements for the other cases (or special cases)

Comment: Very thanks for your reply. But "o'neal" title, I am not getting the right result.

Comment: Just add another 'when' clause to the select where you follow the pattern used for 'Mac' as the basis for e.g. O'Neil or McDonald