# MySQL uppercase sting after space

Tags: mysql

i would like to change "Banana punch" to "Banana Punch" in my DB, but i need a code that would go trough the whole table named "items". Should i check for space in the middle of those 2 words?

Thanks in advance,
Tim.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql

Comment: No, its not the same, i have used this to capitlise the first letter, but if there is a string of 2 words and i want to also capitalise the second word, how do i do that?