# Sql like expresion result too new column

Tags: mysql

Hi everybody I need done help with this issue.

Example myDb tabele name people

```
ID          name        Sex
3   Adam Smith      M
5   Sonia Kolan     F
3   Donald Smith    M
```

Select id, name from people where name LIKE ‚%Smith%’;

Result

```
Id   Name 
3   Adam Smith
3   Donald smith
```

My question is how to transform my result of col name to this view

```
Id   name  
3    Smith 
3    Smith
```

I want too see in col name Expresion from like statement

Comment: I think this is a duplicated question of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4263272/3317006

Comment: Sorry, you wanna a case sensitive results?

Comment: What name should be shown in case `John Smithson`? Is it should to be `Smith` or `Smithson`

Answer (score 1):

> I want too see in col name Expresion from like statement

Then just put that literal string in the `select` clause:

```
select id, 'Smith' name
from people 
where name like '%Smith%'
```

Comment: `'Smith' AS name` for postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the table a query that returns only `'Smith'`:

```
select p.id, t.name 
from people p
inner join (select 'Smith' name) t
on p.name LIKE concat('%', t.name, '%');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=68c436e0f80c47b05c635ea50b3e4410).

```
Results:
> id | name 
> -: | :----
>  3 | Smith
>  3 | Smith
```